# Is there any way to downgrade my Mac mini to Mojave 10.14.3?

Tags: mojave

I updated my Mac mini to Catalina an this broke an important app I use. I think downgrading to 10.14.3 will make it work again (a colleague of mine has their Mac mini at this version and the app works) Is there a way I can downgrade it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind setting up the system afresh, you can wipe your disk clean and perform a fresh install of macOS Mojave by using a bootable USB installer or Internet recovery.